# Why we can not access the objects outside the loop after initializing it inside the loop in java?

Tags: java

```
public class oopInJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Intger num1;

        for( int i=0;i<=10;i++ ){
            num1 = new Intger(i);
        }

        System.out.println(num1.num);


    }
}

class Intger{
    int num;
    
    Intger( int num ){
        this.num = num;
    }

    Intger(){

    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Object is destroyed");
    }
}
```

Here after 10'th iteration shouldn't I have my num1 pointing to an object in heap ? when I did `System.out.println(num1.num);` it says the local variable may not have been initialized. Or did all the objects got destroyed by automatic garbage collection ? If so how does the garbage collection works exactly ? For the 10 objects they shouldn't have any reference variable pointing to them so they could be destroyed but for the 11'th object isn't there num1 still pointing to it ? Then how can garbage collection remove an object which is still pointed by a reference variable ?

Comment: To solve your issue simply change `Intger num1;` to `Intger num1 = null;` which means a null pointer exception will be thrown if the object is not initialized but still referenced. The reason for the error is that if you do not do this, then the behaviour is undefined, and your compiler will not allow that.

Comment: yeah, that solves it. But I didn't initialize num1 to null because num1 was anyway going to be initialized inside the loop, so I didn't bother initializing, I just declared it. Or is this the better practice to initialize to null at the time of declaring? Was I following the wrong practice then ??

Answer (score 4):

It's because you did not initialise the Intger object. You wrote:

```
Intger num1;
```

And only then in the for-loop did you assign an instance to the variable num1. Now, it cannot be guaranteed that the loop ever *gets* executed (even though it might seem obvious in this case), but it is assumed that loops may not execute, so in that case num1 would never have been initialised and you can't access fields of an object that does not exist.

If you instead wrote:

```
Intger num1 = new Intger();
```

It would work and print 10 to the console like you expected it to.

Comment: Yeah that solves it, so does it mean the instances must be initialized no matter what at the time of declaring, even of to null ?

Answer (score 2):

GC has nothing to do with the error. The java compiler is just not smart enough to figure out `num1` definitely gets initialized when the for loop ends. To fix this, you can try `Integer num1 = null;`. This gives `num1` an initial value, and `javac` is satisfied and won't annoy you anymore.

GC will only destroy inaccessible objects. Accessible objects will never be destroyed. In brief, an accessible object is an object that is referenced (here means strong reference, not soft or weak reference) by a static field of a class loaded by the system class loader, a local variable, a running `Thread`, etc. All the objects referenced by other accessible objects is also considered accessible. In this case, the first 10 objects are no longer referenced because the next loop assigns a new object to the variable, throwing away the old one, so they are no longer accessible. Therefore, before the method ends, the first 10 objects are likely to be destroyed, but the last one won't. (Can't explain this well, hope you understand)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your custom class `Intger` is irrelevant. You could just as well use the usual class, `Integer`, to see the same effects.

Also by the way, [`Object#finalize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) is now deprecated, and will eventually be removed. Best to avoid that method for several reasons. See [*JEP 421: Deprecate Finalization for Removal*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/421).

---

## "may not have been initialized" warning

As for you problems, both the [Comment by sorifiend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399946/why-we-can-not-access-the-objects-outside-the-loop-after-initializing-it-inside#comment127900563_72399946) and the [Answer by Easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400162/642706) are correct.

> it says the local variable may not have been initialized

This is a cautionary warning. Your IDE/compiler are mentioning that depending on conditions at runtime, the reference variable you define early on, and then use further down, may not have ever been assigned a value.

You may clear the warning by merely assigning `null`, as shown in the Comment. By assigning `null`, you make clear that you understand the value may continue to be null further down, later in the code.

```
Intger num1 = null ;  // Explicitly assign `null` to the reference variable.
```

## Null check

You could put a null-check in that later code. Change this:

```
System.out.println( num1.num );
```

… to this:

```
if ( Objects.nonNull( num1 ) ) 
{
    System.out.println( num1.num ); 
}
else
{
    System.out.println( "Oops, num1 is null." );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intger num1;
```

Is not initialize outside of for loop so not possible to access outside of forloop

```
public class oopInJava {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a;
    for( int i=0;i<=10;i++ ){
        a = i;
    }
    System.out.println(a);

}
```

}

this gives you same error you got:
/oopInJava.java:8: error: variable a might not have been initialized
System.out.println(a);
^
1 error

this only can solve by initializing outside of for loop

```
public class oopInJava {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = 0;
    for( int i=0;i<=10;i++ ){
        a = i;
    }
    System.out.println(a);

}
```

}

Output: 10

To solve your issue initialize outside for loop as

```
Intger num1 = null;
```

or

```
Intger num1 = new Intger();
```